# Android: Ice Creame Sandwich like tab layout

Tags: android

How can I create Ice Cream Sandwich like tab layout in API Level 10?

[Image Preview http://docs.xamarin.com/@api/deki/files/482/=23_-_Tabs.png](http://docs.xamarin.com/@api/deki/files/482/=23_-_Tabs.png)

I don't know how to customize the tab layout. I have already implemented Action Bar, I want tabs below it.

*Gradient Action Bar and gradient Tabs below it, doesn't look cool.

Comment: use http://actionbarsherlock.com/ this library, I am using too it works like charm,

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ActionBar` to create such tab. Since `ActionBar` is supported from android 3.0, there is a support package for older version.

You can use `ActionBarSherlock` .

```
The library will automatically use the native action bar when available or will automatically wrap a custom implementation around your layouts. This allows you to easily develop an application with an action bar for every version of Android back through 1.6.
```

Visit ActionBarSherlock address - [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

**Edit :** Check this [Application](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/). It uses the `ActionBarSherlock` for supporting older versions.

Comment: Did you get the image from this [link](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Introduction_to_Ice_Cream_Sandwich)

Comment: yes! I'm able to draw the upper-bottom lines, but not able to increase the thickness of selected tab's bottom line.

Comment: Yes, I get image from that website.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is Action Bar Tabs. They old way, TabHost is deprecated.

Here's a good link to get you started on implementing them. [Action Bar User Interface.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) And here's a [full example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/ActionBarTabs.html) brought to you by Google. As for styling the ActionBar and the tabs, [here's a great example.](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html)

Comment: Okay, so, my answer is still what you're looking for. Click those links, buddy.

Comment: I do not see anything about TabHost being deprecated in the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html